Read/Write file mapping integrity
I have a pretty large set (order of tens of GBs) of persistent data, and a server that's supposed to operate on it, and eventually modify it. The server should compile on Windows and Linux 64-bit systems.
File mapping seems a natural choice. This, however, raises questions regarding the data integrity. Changes done to the memory pages are reflected in the underlying file asynchronously. And in case of abnormal termination (server process crash, or power shutdown) the data is likely to end up in an inconsistent state.
I'd like to solve this using a transaction-like technique. That is, all the changes done to the file mapping should be considered as "temporary", and in case of abnormal termination there should be a way to roll them back. At some point the changes should be "committed", that should be an atomic operation, after which the changes are considered persistent.
So far I came up with the following design strategies, and would be happy to hear more ideas and suggestions.

WAL journal file, with explicit write access request.

Whenever an application needs a write access to a memory page, it will call an appropriate function. If this is the 1st time the page is about to be modified (since the last commit) - its contents will be saved in a journal file.
Then, in order to commit the changes, the following will be done:

Flush the journal file (FlushFileBuffers on Windows, fsync on Linux).
Flush the file mapping (FlushViewOfFile on Windows, msync on Linux).
Flush the underlying mapping file.
Resize the journal file to 0.
Flush the journal file. And, optionally, delete it.

Next time the app the app is initialized, and there's a journal file with non-zero size - this means the last changes were not committed, and they need to be rolled-back. During the roll-back the pages are read from the journal file, and copied into the original data file.
Note: the above guarantees consistency in case we assume that file I/O, albeit asynchronous, is executed in-order. Means, if we copy the page contents to the journal file, and then modify the being-accessed memory, which will in turn generate I/O to the data file, those 2 asynchronous I/Os are executed in-order, i.e. journal file gets updated before the data file.

Implicit write access, triggered via access violation.

The same as above, except the application doesn't request the write access explicitly. Instead the file is mapped as read-only (PAGE_READONLY). Whenever an application tries to write to this location, an exception is raised. On Windows it can be handled via SEH, on Linux it should be possible to handle the SIGSEGV signal handler.
During the handling, the page contents are saved to the journal file, and its protection is modified to PAGE_READWRITE.
Then, during the commit, the read-only page protection is restored.
I've already implemented this on Windows, seems to work correctly, and I believe there should be possible to do the same on Linux.

Use copy-on-write memory protection.
This is a rough idea, I don't figure-out all the details yet, but theoretically it's possible to use memory protection PAGE_WRITECOPY (not sure if a similar protection exists on Linux).
By such all the dirty pages will be allocated by the OS automatically, the data fill will be left infact. Then, during the commit stage, those pages should be identified, and copied into the underlying data file (with WAL protection), and then pages state protection should be restored.

File with journal support.
Theoretically, there should be a way to handle this at the file system level. That is, the memory mapping should be supported by a file, that supports transaction mode. All the changes to the file should be treated as temporary until the file is "committed", and rolled-back if the file is closed without such a commit.



So, those are the ideas I came up with.
Option (1) seems like the "safest" option, is it doesn't interfere with things like exception/signal handling. There's also less performance hit when the page is being-written for the 1st time (exception handling is known to be heavy).
It has, however, the following drawbacks:

Need to call an explicit function each time we're supposed to modify data. Need to update all the code that is supposed to work on this data, which is very inconvenient of course.
It can be costly to check each time is the page is already dirty. Need to have an appropriate data structure (some bitmask, or map, or a combination of those). In case where many modifications happen in the same page (which is likely to happen) this can be more impactful, than handling an OS exception/signal only once.

Option (2) seems more risky. But so far I could write a proof-on-concept, and it seems to work just fine.
Option (3) - I don't know if it's even possible, i.e. is there's a conventional API for this. But theoretically it could be beneficial, since the copy-on-write is handled entirely in the kernel mode, no need to handle those things explicitly.
And, lastly, Option (4). Actually it should be superior in every sense, as the transaction-like behavior happens exactly where it should - on the file level, when the file mapping changes are finally flushed. Also the fastest, and the simplest w.r.t. coding.
The only question: is this ever possible? Is there a file system available that supports this?
Those are my ideas so far. Will be glad to hear more.
Thanks in advance.

In general, I'd be vary of using mmap for read-write data if you need some kind of transactional safety for your writes. It's surprisingly tricky to handle everything correctly.
A good place to start is the recent(ish) paper https://db.cs.cmu.edu/mmap-cidr2022/
From the conclusions of that paper:
When you should not use mmap in your DBMS:
• You need to perform updates in a transactionally safe fashion.
• You want to handle page faults without blocking on slow I/O
or need explicit control over what data is in memory.
• You care about error handling and need to return correct results.
• You require high throughput on fast persistent storage devices.
When you should maybe use mmap in your DBMS:
• Your working set (or the entire database) fits in memory and
the workload is read-only.
• You need to rush a product to the market and do not care about
data consistency or long-term engineering headaches.
• Otherwise, never.

Now, depending on the kind of data you're handling, if at all suitable, look into adopting sqlite rather than DIY.

Wow! Thanks, that was very educative.

Worth to mention that my use case is not a DBMS, my data size is many orders of magnitude less. But I also had that gut feeling that giving OS full control of the I/O isn't a good idea.
So, I guess, I should either continue with virtual memory approach, but handle page load/write myself. Or give up on working with my data directly, and use traditional I/O.
Right?
